# Is it possible to install gnome-shell extended places extension in 12.04

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

Just upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10 and am working through updating/replacing Gnome-shell extensions. One particularly useful extension was: Gnome-shell extended places, which included shortcuts to Filezilla FTP sites, but also Virtualbox machines. Is it possible to install this in gnome-shell 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right there are at least two extensions for places.

I dont know if this extension will fullfill your needs but I quickly found this extension

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/8/places-status-indicator/

and there was another similar extension more (i didnt found it in my quick serch)

Comment: Unfortunately, this one doesn't do Filezilla and Virtualbox as best as I can tell...

Comment: I found the mentioned second "places" app. It seems to be much more powerfull than the first one. But it hasnt shortcuts for filezilla or virtual box either. Anyhow I think its worth to have a look at it. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/299/all-in-one-places/

Comment: Actually using this one...